# How can I know if an anime is episodic or has a continuous plot?

Tags: resources

I keep searching for a website or forum that can classify an anime as episodic without reading reviews or plots (because I really hate spoilers), but I couldn't find any.

Is there a way to know if a series is episodic in nature much like *Samurai Champloo* or *Gintama* where each episode has a stand-alone story or if it has a continuous plot across all episodes like *Bleach* or *Naruto*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anime-Planet has an [`episodic`](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/episodic) tag which gives you what you want. [AniList](https://anilist.co/search/anime?includedTags=Episodic) and [AniDB](https://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=tag&tagid=6399) also have their own episodic tag. ANN, MAL and Kitsu don't seem to provide this feature as far as I know.

Answer (score -2):

Just write the name of anime plus 'serial'
For example naruto serial. If it continuous they will say somewhere in your searches 'serial TV show'
Or try bleach serial. They say 'serial TV show 2004-2012'
So you know it is serial/continuous
If it is episodic like gintama they won't say. Although that doesn't mean it is not serial (sorry)